# Last element should not wrap first

Tags: html, css

In this layout two items float left and one floats right:
http://jsfiddle.net/RgkRq/9/

```
.content {
    background-color: red;
    float:left;
    width: 300px;
}
.menu {
    float:right;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: green;
}

<DIV class="container">
    <div class="content">CONTENT</DIV>
    <div class="content">CONTENT</DIV>
    <div class="menu">MENU</DIV>
</DIV>
```

When the page shrinks, the last element will wrap under the two others, but I want it to stay there and make the others wrap first.

I know, I can achieve this by changing their order in html, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3vVwp/1/

My Question is: Is there any way i can get this behaviour in css without changing the html?

Thanks
Hannes

Comment: The two examples behave the same way.

Comment: Dont you think it shoud go responsive?

Comment: @Shomz Sorry, i messed up the urls, now its correct.

Comment: No problem. Reordering seems the most natural solution - any other hackish way of achieving this will probably mostly depend on reordering items as well. Any particular reason you don't want to change the order?

Comment: You can use [Flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/). Which can keep your HTML content as you like, and you can also change their appearance order from CSS, setting the `box-ordinal-group` property

Comment: @Shomz Well, i was not sure if i missed any css3 feature which could help me with that, so i don't have to change all my views html. I don't want to use any hacks, like reorder this with jquery. So i gonna change the html now. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: I think you're doing the right thing. Even if there was something you can do with css3, you might risk how would it behave in different browsers, etc... A good idea for the future is to use templates, so that you can change only your menu (or header) template, and the menus change all across the website. You're welcome! :)

Comment: @Abhishek That's what I ended up with.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but it might be an alternative to what you're asking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/RgkRq/11/

The menu has a fixed width, and the content divs shrink (flexible width). When the column widths reach the minimum they can, then the menu width shrinks.

What I have done is set the container div as display:table, and the child divs as display:table-cell:

```
.container {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.content {
    background-color: red;
    display:table-cell;
    border-right:10px solid #fff;
}
.menu {
    width: 150px;
    background-color: green;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

The border-right is used to separate the content into columns.

You will want to check this for browser support, as older browsers don't support display:table.

Comment: In this solution, there is no more wrapping. I want it to wrap but need to change it, so that the first items wrap first.